# Android studio Firebase and Github pushing and cloning

Tags: android, git, firebase, github

I have created a small project for user register and login in(Authentication) android studio using firebase and it was working fine. Basically i need to keep this project on github, I have moved to project to my desktop and then pushed it to github. My version of the project works, however, the cloned project doesn't seem to work as it just keeps loading when the user wants to register or login.

Also, it comes up with some errors like missing iml's or that the app has multiple slice apk's and need to uninstall.

My question is what steps do I need to undertake to make sure that the application will work when pushed to a github repo and then cloned back from the repo, so that the application runs when downloaded on any pc, and do i have to do anything to the firebase?

since what i see is that everything is in place, package name hasnt changed, all files and dependencies are present.

Comment: This looks like a problem with the sha1 key fingerprint on firebase. In firebase go to project settings and then check if your sha1 key matches or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all i was using Email and password authentication.

Secondly the issue was that the google play was not updated inside of the emulator.

For anyone that runs into the same problem click the three dots at the bottom of the emulator panel and go into "Google Play" and update.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you didn't specify what authentication you are using. For example if you are using facebook you need to add to the Facebook developers page the sha1 key fingerprint for each device you are going to install the app.

Secondly I have deployed my firebase project to github and working from my mac and windows machine without any problem syncing with Firebase. In firebase project settings as I can see I haven't added any SHA certificate fingerprint.

Make sure that you have added on Github all the SHA certificate fingerprint from any pc that you are planning to clone the project.